# Copying Files to Another Folder While Keeping a Single Parent Directory

Tags: powershell

I'm still new to PowerShell and I'm trying to do something I haven't seen an exact answer for yet. We have one large folder with many subfolders that contain individual audio files (our phone system records and places audio files in folders by date). I want to get certain files from within those folders and move them to a different folder, but I want to create the parent folder that the files came from in the new location. I am not grabbing all files within the folders, only a few. For example:

I want to move a file at C:\CopyFrom\02182019\AudioFile.wav

I have a folder at C:\CopyTo, but I want the destination to be C:\CopyTo\02182019\AudioFile.wav

I want the script to create the folder if it doesn't exist, but copy the files into the folder if it does.

I'm currently using `Get-ChildItem -Include` to get the files I need and piping it into a foreach loop that I found online. This is as close as I've gotten to what I need, but it copies the ENTIRE folder structure, starting at the root, so my destination ends up being:
C:\CopyTo\CopyFrom\02182019\AudioFile.wav

Here is what I have so far:

```
Get-ChildItem $SourceFolder -Include $ExtArray -Recurse | forEach {
## Remove the original  root folder

  $split = $_.Fullname  -split '\\'

  $DestFile =  $split[1..($split.Length - 1)] -join '\' 

  ## Build the new  destination file path

  $DestFile =  "C:\DestinationFolder\$DestFile"

  ## Copy-Item won't  create the folder structure so we have to 

  ## create a blank file  and then overwrite it

  $null = New-Item -Path  $DestFile -Type File -Force

  Copy-Item -Path  $_.FullName -Destination $DestFile -Force

}
```

I found the foreach loop in [this article](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2015/10/22/maintain-folder-structure.aspx). I'm assuming there is more I can add to the $split line that will allow me to shave off the rest of the directory structure, but I'm still pretty new to this and don't understand the syntax well enough.

I know this is kind of convoluted to explain, so please let me know if any clarification is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ExtArray = "keep"
$SourceFolder = "C:\source"
$DestFolder = "C:\dest"

Get-ChildItem $SourceFolder -Recurse -Include "*keep*"  | foreach {

    $source_dir = $_.DirectoryName
    $dest_dir = $_.DirectoryName.replace($SourceFolder, $DestFolder)

    if (Test-Path $dest_dir) {
      Copy-Item -Path $_ -Destination $dest_dir -Recurse
    } else {
      New-Item -Path $dest_dir -ItemType "directory" | out-null
      Copy-Item -Path $_ -Destination $dest_dir -Recurse
    }

}
```

Comment: This looks like the right track, but the destination folder needs to be dynamically pulled from the source folder if that makes sense. Each day a new folder is created for that day's recordings from our phone system. I want the script to be able to scan through the entire top level folder, check the audio files in a subfolder for a certain string using -Include, and move those audio files into the destination while also copying it's parent directory. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I couldn't comment before so I had to post an answer but see if this gets you want you need.

Comment: @TheLukeBagel the -errorAction is because Copy-Item will display an error if the file already exists. We can add a conditional check and skip the file if it exists at the destination.

Comment: I apologize for the late reply, we had another project come up that pushed this to the side temporarily. I just tried your suggestion here, and it gets me very close. However, it seems to be copying the entire folder instead of the list that is being piped from Get-ChildItem. The destination folder is also very close to what I need, as it creates the parent folder as I need it to, but it also creates another copy of that folder within the destination and copies all the files again over to that folder, so I end up with C:\target\folder1\audiofiles and C:\target\folder1\folder1\sameaudiofiles.

Comment: Added another example.

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much for your help! You are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt at this - I set the top level directory as one variable and the underlying folder structure as another.

```
$File = "C:\test\IT\testfile.docx"
$Destination  = "C:\test2\"
$test2 = "\IT\"

mkdir "$Destination\$test2"
Copy-Item -Path $File -Destination "$Destination\$test2" -recurse
```

I'm not sure how to implement this into your current code but hopefully it gets the wheels spinning and sends you in the right direction!

Comment: Wouldn't this just create C:\test2\IT and place everything there? Is there a way to have the $test2 variable pull the first level parent directory name that the file came from? Each of these files could be coming from a different subdirectory, but I would like to keep their single first level parent directory. The forEach block in my original post gets me very close, but adds the complete file path minus C:. I'd like to get rid of everything up to the last subdirectory\filename.